# проблемы с thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

помогите разобраться thymeleaf, в документации к релизу thymeleaf сказано, что требуется минимум JDK 17, но если я устанавливаю в пропетых <java.version>17</java.version>, у меня при компиляции выпалывает:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/Users/uncleden/Downloads/geek-shopping-list-part-1/target/classes/ru/geekbrains/GeekShoppingListApplication.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [/Users/uncleden/Downloads/geek-shopping-list-part-1/target/classes/ru/geekbrains/GeekShoppingListApplication.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
```

Также возникает проблема, если я указываю версию: spring-boot-starter-parent выше 2.7, тогда thymeleaf перестает работает с атрибутами "${}" .

Единственная связка, в которой у меня все работает без проблем - это:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

и:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
```

Помогите мигрировать на последние версии.

Comment: Попробуйте создать свой проект с помощью Spring Initializr'a. Если вы используете Ultimate edition то вы можете просто его выбрать в сайдбаре Generators про создании нужного проекта. Если же вы используете Community edition то воспользуйтесь сайтом https://start.spring.io

Answer (score 0):

скажите, если не видит атрибутов, возможно в HTML - xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org". Возможно забыли вставить, данную ссылку.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).